# Do the lowest population US states directly receive funding from other states?

Tags: united-states, taxes, infrastructure

I was told states like Montana with high infrastructure costs relative to population receive funds from states like New York. Is there a state-to-state funding system like this in place? If so, which states are givers and receivers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. This funding is indirect, as it flows through the federal government first. All states contribute to the federal budget (via their citizen's taxes). It's just that some states contribute to the federal government more than they receive in return (Such as New York) and some contribute less than they receive in return (such as Montana)

This chart shows the amount of money a state receives from the federal government for each dollar its citizens pay in federal taxes:

[image]
Src: http://www.theatlantic.com/business/archive/2014/05/which-states-are-givers-and-which-are-takers/361668/

There's a lot of reasons for this, but comparing Montana and New York, it's likely simply population differences.

Comment: "but comparing Montana and New York, it's likely simply population differences" ??? Why? It's money a state gets by "each dollar its citizens pay in federal taxes". I'd say that the main reason is that on average people (and companies)  have a greater income or are wealthier in New York than in Montana. I know nothing about these particular states, but this is generally what happens when a region/state is wealthier than another within a country. Wealthier people pay more taxes, so the more wealthier a state is, the more it contributes.

Comment: @drake again *there are lots of reasons for this* but in this case, Montana is one of the least populated states, and New York is one of the most populated states. However, Montana is one of the largest states by size and, as such, still has a demand for large infrastructure costs. You're absolutely right, wealth would have a lot to do with it too. And may very well play a part but there's such a drastic population difference between these two states that that is likely the *primary* factor--but not the only factor for sure.

Comment: A highly populated state that is much less wealthy than the average would rank in the first positions in your list, according to my argument. Of course, there are more reasons than wealth, but it is my understanding that that is the main one.

Comment: @drake I'm not making a list. I'm simply mentioning the two states mentioned by the OP. Take any two states and I'm sure we'll find all sorts of different reasons for the differences. And hey, I might be wrong too. If you find some data, please share!

Comment: I hadn't read your comment. I think I agree with it. Population density (ratio of population and size) and sparsity (whether the population is concentrated in relatively big cities or spread in small towns and villages) is another reason. But not the population per se. Good answer! +1

Comment: Oh! Of course, you are absolutely correct on a broad level. Wealthier states ultimately pay more than poor states. So everything else being equal, wealthier states would be supporting the poorer states. But there are plenty of exceptions (namely because everything else is rarely equal).